# Rails3 Find Wild Card Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a wildcard search, I'm doing something like this

```
@items = Item.where("title =?", "%#{item_to_be_found}%"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `=` for LIKE

```
"title LIKE ?", "%#{...}%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem that does the weight lift for building queries.

`gem act_as_wild_searchable, :git => 'http://github.com/canimus/act_as_wild_searchable.git'`

Consider that you have a model named Product with :name and :description
you can then search

```
Product.name_like? "Camera HD" # Produces where (name like ?, "%Camera HD%")
Product.description_like? "1080p", :left=>true # Produces where (description like ?, "%1080p")
```

I hope it helps!